# Primefaces row select with dialog

Tags: ajax, primefaces, dialog, datatable, row

I have a row listener that triggers a dialog box to pop up with the rows information. When I select a row nothing happens, however when I click the little edit button, the dialog pops up. Do I have my ajax even in the wrong spot? What am I doing wrong?

```
<h:form id="form_dl">
    <p:dataTable id="dl_deployments" var="dl_dep"
        value="#{userWizard.deploymentList}" paginator="true" rows="10"
        rowKey="#{dl_dep}" editable="true"
        filteredValue="#{userWizard.filteredDeployments}"
        selection="#{userWizard.selectedDeployment}" selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":frm_south:form_dl:displayDLPopUp"
            oncomplete="deploymentDialog.show()" />
        <p:column headerText="Project Name" style="width:125px"
            filterBy="#{dl_dep.projectname}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{dl_dep.projectname}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{dl_dep.projectname}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="SR Number" style="width:125px"
            filterBy="#{dl_dep.srnumber}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{dl_dep.srnumber}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{dl_dep.srnumber}" style="width:100%"></p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Grade" style="width:125px"
            filterBy="#{dl_dep.grade}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{dl_dep.grade}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{dl_dep.grade}" style="width:100%"></p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="System" style="width:125px"
            filterBy="#{dl_dep.system}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{dl_dep.system}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{dl_dep.system}" style="width:100%"></p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:50px">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{userWizard.editRowListner}" />
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:dialog id="dl_dialog" header="Deployment Details"
        widgetVar="deploymentDialog" resizable="false" showEffect="fade"
        hideEffect="explode">
        <h:panelGrid id="displayDLPopUp" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
            <h:outputText value="Project Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.selectedDeployment.projectname}" />
            <h:outputText value="SR Number:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.selectedDeployment.srnumber}" />
            <h:outputText value="Grade:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.selectedDeployment.grade}" />
            <h:outputText value="System:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.selectedDeployment.system}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I see `update=":frm_south:form_dl:displayDLPopUp"`, may be form nested form, it not true in html.

Comment: And then change `update=":frm_south:form_dl:displayDLPopUp"`, avoid to update dialog directly.